# SQL Server authentication failed

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server using SQL Server authentication, I am getting the error that says user cannot login.

I made the changes like created a login using SQL Server authentication, checked the instance is in mixed mode, restarted the instance. But still I couldn't connect.

Can anyone of you please help?

Comment: Can you post your server info?

Comment: Look at the user account specifically.  There's a setting to allow it to log in or not when you modify it (right with all the "enforce password policy" stuff). FYI  Creating a user at the database level doesn't create a login, that's at the server level.